# Separate Count for multiple items within a day MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display the status of multiple claims from one day at a time. For example, "date1" has 3 claims. Each claim has a different status. How can I display the status count for ALL claims within "date1". Namely, I would like to order my results by earliest to latest date then have three columns with a count for how many claims from that day have that status. The three status columns should add up to the total number of claims that day. This is what I would like it to look like: (St1 - St3 represent unique statuses)

```
Date      St1 St2 St3
12-02-12 | 1 | 2 | 3
12-03-12 | 2 | 5 | 3
12-04-12 | 7 | 3 | 8
```

The query I started working with looks like this, but it is entirely incorrect.

```
SELECT dates, statuses, COUNT(*) AS St1 FROM table_dates GROUP BY dates;
```

This was my attempt to get the count of only one status. Figured I had to start somewhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(if(statuses = st1,1,0)) as st1, 
SUM(if(statuses = st2,1,0)) as st2, 
SUM(if(statuses = st3,1,0)) as st3 
    FROM table_dates 
    GROUP BY dates;
```

Comment: what do the 1,0 represent in the syntax?

Comment: those are actual numbers - for each query - if the condition result is true - it will return the first value 1, and if false it will return the latter value 0. In this case you will summarize the number of rows where the status is st1 for instance - which is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You want to add status to your GROUP BY:

```
SELECT dates, status, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM table_dates
GROUP BY dates, status
```

This will give your results in a slightly different format from what you asked:

```
Date       | Status | cnt
2012-12-02 | 1      | 1 
2012-12-02 | 2      | 2 
2012-12-02 | 3      | 3 
2012-12-03 | 1      | 2 
2012-12-03 | 2      | 5 
2012-12-03 | 3      | 3 
2012-12-04 | 1      | 7 
2012-12-04 | 2      | 3 
2012-12-04 | 3      | 8
```

This is probably a better format because if you later add new statuses neither your database schema, SQL query, nor client code will need to change.

Comment: Ok, I may be able to work with this. But is there any way to do this using separate columns for each status count instead?

Comment: @user1251693: Yeah it's possible, but it's not really a very good idea. Presentation should be done in the client.

Comment: Well this answered the question I was in the process of writing.